# Is there a programming language where 1/6 behaves the same as 1.0/6.0?

Tags: programming-languages

While I was programming in C++ some days ago, I made this mistake (that I have history of making it!). In one part of my code, I had 1/6 and I was expecting it be 0.16666666666 which is not the case. As you all know the result is 0 - C, C++, Java, Python, all behave the same.

I post it on my Facebook page and now there is debate on if there is a programming language where `1/6` behaves the same as `1.0/6.0`.

Comment: Haskell. 1 / 6 = 0.16666666666666666

Comment: PowerShell generates 0.166666666666667, which surprised me as 1 is an integer. I'd wager there's some other .NET languages which generate the value you expected.

Comment: There is, in theory, an unlimited number of them..  Here's another:  [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com), as well as derivatives like Orca, Red, and so on.  `>> 1 / 6` -> `== 0.166666666666667`

Comment: Lua does this. It only has a single *Number* type, that usually is the same as C's double.

Comment: In Clojure `1/6` is actually 1/6 (fractional type) which, coerced to `Double`, is 1.66666...

Answer (score 18):

Has everyone forgotten Pascal?

`1/6` yields `0.1666666...` (to whatever precision is supported).

`1 div 6` yields `0`

It's arguable whether the C rule is a mistake. Almost all of C's arithmetic operators, where the operands are of the same type, yield a result of the same type. There's something to be said for consistency.

Furthermore, since C is primarily targeted at system-level code, most C programs don't use floating-point at all. At one time, accidentally adding floating-point code to a program that didn't otherwise need it could be a serious problem. That's probably still the case, for small embedded systems -- which, again, are a major target for C.

In most C programs, truncating integer division is probably just what you want anyway.

If `1 / 6` yielded a floating-point result in C, then:

- It would be an inconsistency in the language.
- The standard would have to make an arbitrary choice of *which* floating-point type to use for the result (`double` may seem like the natural choice, but you might prefer the extra precision of `long double`)
- The language would *still* have to have an operation for integer division; performing floating-point addition and then truncating would likely not be good enough.

C *could* have provided separate operators for the two kinds of division, but the second point above would still apply: which of the three floating-point types would be used for the result? And since it's easy enough to get floating-point division if you need it (use a floating-point constant for one or both of the operands, or cast one or both of the operands to a floating-point type), it apparently wasn't considered that important.

In the 1974 version of the C manual (that's 4 years before the publication of the first edition of K&R), Ritchie doesn't even mention the possible confusion:

> The binary / operator indicates division. The same type considerations as for multiplication apply

which says that if both operands are of type `int` or `char`, the result is of type `int`.

Yes, it's a source of confusion for some C programmers, especially beginners -- but C is not noted for being very novice-friendly.

Comment: Pascal. Getting details right before C got them wrong.™

Comment: And then Algol was an improvement over its successors (in the number of which both C and Pascal stand).

Comment: Pascal - getting the details right (give or take a factor of 10)

Comment: I originally wrote `1.666666...`, which is clearly wrong. My lame excuse is that the Pascal test program I wrote printed `1.6666666666666667E-0001`

Answer (score 17):

Actually this behavior was changed in Python 3 and it now does behave like you expect (`//` is now used for integer division).

Comment: Thanks. Any other programming languages do you have in you mind? Basic family maybe?

Comment: @Pouya: This behavior is standard for the Pascal family. `/` always produces a floating-point value, and a separate operator (`div`) is used for integer division.

Answer (score 14):

Out of prominent languages, JavaScript. 1.0/6.0 = 1/6 =
0.16666666666666666.

I don't see this as surprising. As a rule of a thumb, if a language distinguishes between integer and floating point numeric types, dividing two integers will yield a truncated integer instead of float. If it doesn't, most likely it will default to floating point operations. This should be the expected behaviour on the programmer's part.

Just keep in mind that there are additional things that could also be at play here, like the already mentioned separate integer division operator or implicit type casting.

Comment: This is not "a rule of thumb".  It's a rule of C, and a handful of languages that blindly copied C's mistakes.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Did FORTRAN "blindly copy C's mistake"?  I personally believe that well-designed languages should use separate operators for truncated division versus approximate division of integer quantities (and also, btw, for value and referential equality), but the design decision in the days of FORTRAN was probably reasonable.  That doesn't mean every language should do things the way FORTRAN did in the 1950's.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: I find it disputable to view it as a mistake, especially in the context of C itself. Regardless however of our opinions, enough popular languages follow that pattern - both those that default to integer division and those that don't - to call it a rule of thumb. It's an observation, not a sentiment.

Comment: Lower level languages need to make these distinctions. Higher level/dynamic languages are often better off without them. It's a design trade-off. I appreciate just having one big dumb Number constructor/type in JS, but I imagine I'd be feeling JS was lacking when trying to write a high performance 3D engine without stricter type control. JS may have overlapping utility with other languages but I don't think anybody is ever going to consider it a goto for writing high performance closer-to-the-chrome type stuff.

Comment: @scrwtp: Division is a well-defined mathematical concept.  When I can divide 3 by 2 and get something other than 1.5, that's objectively incorrect.  And when the way that I write the 3 or the 2 determines whether or not I get the correct answer, that's just asking for hard-to-debug errors to show up in the code.

Comment: Mathematics outside of programming considers integer-only rules for division.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You sir are not an engineer.  You clearly have no understanding of *how* or *why* C behaves the way it does.  Please don't ignorantly call it a mistake -- it's not posh.  I don't feel the need to entertain you with the details because I imagine you probably wouldn't read them, but here's a hint: C != Math, and is not, and never was, a mathematical language or even an attempt at one.

Comment: @DavidCowden But integer division is a general mathematical concept. C's not being weird. It's just offering more possibilities to take advantage of or trip over as the case may be.

Comment: @DavidCowden: On the contrary, I have a very clear understanding of why it does what it does. And "mathematical language" or no, (what does that even mean?), the fact is that *division is a mathematical concept*, and a clearly-defined one at that.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Simply, C is a programming language -- written to operate on machines where "integers" are limited to the number of bits the processor's adder has. The notion of a *floating point* number or even a fraction is not natural to programming.  It is needed for data representation and mathematics, but in no way is it useful to programming logic. C makes the [necessary] distinction between the two operations based implicitly on the types of the division operands. From a top-down outlook, C made a "mistake". From the bottom up, languages that don't make the distinction are too general.

Comment: Please do note that I neither judge nor care whether the 'C way' is correct or incorrect from the mathematical point of view, nor is this the subject of the question being asked. I'm merely stating a simple observation that might be helpful in avoiding the hard-to-debug errors you mention. I have also pointed out separate division operators as one of the things to look out for in a language. I don't feel my answer justifies such a heated discussion. As things are, C-derived languages overload the division operator, Pascal-derived use separate. Nothing more to add.

Comment: @DavidCowden: And yet somehow Pascal, which predates C and had the same (if not stricter) early-generation hardware constraints to work within, managed to get it right.  I agree that the distinction is necessary.  But making it implicit instead of explicit is a good way to end up with bugs that are both easy to make and hard to fix, because there's nothing explicitly written there in the code to cause them.  (It's much easier to debug a problem based on something being there that shouldn't than one based on something *not* being there that should.)

Comment: All I'm saying is it's relative to which paradigm you're operating in.  Outside of mathematical operations, the extra data that Pascal provides is baggage, and to others who need that information, it's not.  For a systems programmer, dividing two `int`s and getting a `double` makes *no* sense, and is, in fact, *not* what's expected.  I understand what you're getting at, but it's a mistake to call the design decision made by K&R a mistake.  That's all..

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Programming is not pure math.  Mathematically, 1/6 is a rational number and cannot be exactly represented by binary floating point number.  The only precise representation is as a ratio with a denominator six times the numerator.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Do you extend your 3/2 example to say 1/3. Currently in all  languages I know of even floating point 1/3 is not the same as 1/3 mathematically.

Comment: @MasonWheeler, division is indeed a well-defined mathematical concept. Following that argument through logically, given that a 32-bit integer type is a model of the ring `Z/ 2^32 Z` you should expect that division by an even integer should sometimes raise an exception. Division by odd integers would always be ok, though, because they have multiplicative inverses mod 2^32.

Answer (score 7):

There are many languages where `((1/6)*6)` results in 1, not in 0. For example, PL/SQL, many BASIC dialects, Lua.

<sub>Accidentally, in all those langauges 1/6 results in .166666667, or 0.16666666666667 or something similar. I chose the ((1/6)*6)==1 variant to get rid of those little differences.</sub>

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: Accidentally, in all those langauges 1/6 results in .166666667, or 0.16666666666667 or something similar. I chose the `((1/6)*6)==1` variant to get rid of those little differences, but it looks like I overestimated the math skills of some people.

Comment: @RocMartí yes, it really is...

Comment: I would be surprised to see (1.0/6.0)*6 being exactly equal to 1! The rounding of the result of (1.0/6.0) will lead to a small difference. (Although there will be a few languages that default to infinite precision)

Comment: @Sjoerd: It's not too surprosing that it's exact, actually.  Consider in decimal the scenario of 1/11 * 11 with all values accurate to five significant figures.  The value of 1/11 is 9.0909 * 10^-2.  Multiply by 11 and one would get 99.9999 * 10/-2 before rounding.  Round to five significant figures and the result will be 1.0000 * 10^0.  Note that the key is that the mantissa of 1/6 is "...0101010101...".  If the last bit of a representation is a "1", multiplying it by six and rounding will yield 1.  If the last bit were zero, it would not.

Comment: Sjoerd: Those I testet (Oracle SQL and Lua) output 1.

Comment: @Supercat Okay, you could be right that (1.0/6.0)*6.0 might be rounded twice, resulting in exactly 1.0. However, if (1.0/6.0)*6.0 happens to be 1.0, (1.0/3.0)*3.0 will not, and vice versa. So whether the result is 'correct' depends on bit representation of the numbers, and it will not be correct for all values.

Comment: @user281377 Printed values usually are rounded to avoid values like 1.0000000000001. Try `((1/6)*6 - 1)`. And as @supercat noted, it might be coincide that it works for 6, so please try `(1/3)*3-1` (and 6, and 7, ...) as well.

Comment: @Sjoerd: The issue isn't just one of output; many numbers will round, *during computation*, to the exactly-correct value.  Because 1/6 is 1.010101... * 2^-3 and 1/2 is 1.010101... * 2^-2, 1.0/3.0 will work just as well as 1.0/6.0.  Actually, when using double-precision floating-point numbers, the expression ((1.0/N)*N == 1.0) will be true for 853,037,383 of the first 1,000,000,000 values of N including all values below 49; the expression (n/d)*d==n will be true for many whole-number `double` pairs as well; the smallest `d` where it fails is with 29/7.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell treats 1/6 and 1.0/6.0 as being identically 0.16666666666666666. It also renders 1/6.0 and 1.0/6 as being that same value as well.

This is due to the basic numerical types in Haskell not being quite the same as other languages. True integer division is somewhat...complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Perl does. The one-liner

```
perl -e '$x=1/6;print "$x\n";'
```

results in the output of:

```
0.166666666666667
```

I believe that PHP works the same way.

**Edited to add:** I also believe that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for `1/6 == 1.0/6.0` is for the language in question to be weakly typed.

Comment: Why the heck would weak typing (whatever that's supposed to mean) be necessary? Just define / to (also) mean float division in the case of both arguments being integers.

Comment: @delnan - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing I suppose it might be possible to have a strongly typed language in which `/` is automatically overloaded depending on the types of the arguments, but that seems like a violation of [the Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) to me...

Comment: [Weak/strong typing is ill-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760) (as wiki also implies), please avoid it and be specific. I take it your definition bans implicit conversion, but not ad-hoc polymorphism? If so, consider Haskell, which has no implicit conversions but pretty well-executed (as in, works 99% of the time and can be comprehended by mortals) numeric polymorphism. And why would this be astonishing? It would be far more astonishing (not to say annoying) to me if I had to add a number of dots to every single instance of any operator, depending on the exact precision I wish.

Comment: @JackManey I think to most newcomers it is way more surprising that 1/2 should equal 0 than it is if dividing two integers results in a double. After all integers aren't closed under division in maths either. Also as delnan points out, Haskell is an example of a strongly typed language in which / on two integers, doesn't produce an integer. And Python 3 is another.

Comment: The Haxe language is strongly (albeit inferred) typed, and yet it has no integer division, only float. So there you go.

Comment: @sepp2k "I think to most newcomers.."  << It's not the newcomers, but rather the people who are well versed in the use of a language and it's application domain that should define its' rules.  To me, dividing two ints should result in an int and is the least astonishing result.  If you want a double, cast the ints to a double and divide them.  Simple.  And yes, a web developer may disagree.

Comment: @DavidCowden Not only web developers might disagree. What a well versed programmer does or doesn't find surprising depends entirely on what programming language he's well versed in. (Obviously all design decisions of a given language are not astonishing to people who are completely familiar with that particular language, so that's a meaningless metric). Dividing two ints resulting in an int is only least astonishing to you because you're used to it. Mathematically speaking it's completely astonishing. Integer division is not even associative.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I agree, I was using web developer as an example simply to hint at the point you just made explicite (= What it comes down to is that it's a design decision personal to each language how integer division is handled.  If one disagrees with how a certain language handles things, there should be no trouble finding another one (=

Answer (score 2):

In Squeak Smalltalk `/` on integers creates Fraction objects. So while this is not the same as float division, still `(1/6)*6` returns 1.

Comment: In all Smalltalk-80 derivates (that is, nearly all Smalltalks). Amber is one of contemporary exceptions (which is understandable, being compiled to JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I just checked my [TI-99/4A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-99/4A)'s built in [TI BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_BASIC_%28TI_99/4A%29). As it treats all numeric expressions as floating point, the division operation is floating point as well.

```
 TI BASIC READY
>PRINT 1/6
  .1666666667

>
```

Answer (score 2):

VB ([VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx) , [VB6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242772%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), VBA...)

The integer division operator is \

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB.  Numeric literals are doubles by default.

```
>> 1/6
ans =
    0.1667
```

Answer (score 2):

Clojure does use fractions by default. It's not the same as 1.0/6.0, but you can convert to it with `float` or `double` when you need.

```
user=> (/ 1 6)
1/6
user=> (* (/ 1 6) 2)
1/3
user=> (pos? (/ 1 6)) ; Is 1/6 > 0?
true
user=> (float (/ 1 6))
0.16666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it seems to work properly in **Windows PowerShell** *(version 3)*.

```
PS C:\> 1.0 / 6.0
0.166666666666667

PS C:\> 1/6
0.166666666666667
```

Also seems to work in Python 3 as sepp2k mentioned. The other two languages I have readily available on REPL, Scala and Ruby, both do integer division and yield 0.

Answer (score 0):

The Rexx language always produces an arithmetically correct answer. For example: 5/2 = 2.5. Rexx is a great language that has not been utilized enough. In theory, when a compiler can't determine what do you want, its better to do the correct math, however, this may not be efficient. Rexx also provides the // operator.